# okhttp3 how to set Dns

Tags: java, android, http, okhttp

I need set a DNS in my app.

I can't figure out how to add it:

```
//Http Client
OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    client.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    client.dns("172.10.0.100");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the DNS via the WIFI settings and then just do this:

```
client.dns(Dns.SYSTEM);
```

now it should get the info from there.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of setting an alternative DNS strategy or per host overrides

```
Dns dns = ...
builder.dns(dns);
```

[DnsOverride.kt](https://github.com/yschimke/okurl/blob/488c6cd1363472b5f8840090dac5e78d02285f28/src/main/kotlin/com/baulsupp/okurl/network/DnsOverride.kt)

[DnsSelector.kt](https://github.com/yschimke/okurl/blob/488c6cd1363472b5f8840090dac5e78d02285f28/src/main/kotlin/com/baulsupp/okurl/network/DnsSelector.kt)

Comment: Links are dead.

Answer (score 0):

See this post [dns-android-okhttp](https://garage.easytaxi.com/tag/dns-android-okhttp/) and add dependency which I defined below, and it will work :)

> compile 'dnsjava:dnsjava:2.1.7'